# Console Status Update Text Messages

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a working Google Apps script that displays a single web app output at the end.

The script lasts about ~20 seconds,
and I'm looking to improve the user experience,
by intermittently update the script status during this period.

I understand the challenges of asynchronous server/client operation,
but I'm surprised that such "trivial" functionaly seems quite hard to realize.

I reviewed similar topics, but miss a good example.

Code Example :

```
function doGet(e){
  output = function1();
  output = function2();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(output).
}

function function1() {
 //DoSomething
 return = "output1";
}

function function2() {
 //DoSomething
 return = "output2";
}
```

I'm not looking to replace the function calls by HTML calls.
But maybe continously poll a global variable until script execution is completed, if this is feasible?

Maybe to make it more concrete,

code.gs:

```
var data = "test";
Logger.log(data);

function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function main() {
  data = "1";
  pushMSG(data);
  Logger.log(data);
  Utilities.sleep(2000);

  data = "2";
  pushMSG(data);
  Logger.log(data);
  Utilities.sleep(2000);

  data = "3";
  pushMSG(data);
  Logger.log(data);
  Utilities.sleep(2000);

  data = "4";
  pushMSG(data);
  Logger.log(data);
  Utilities.sleep(2000);

  data = "5";
  pushMSG(data);
  Logger.log(data);
  Utilities.sleep(2000);
}

function pushMSG(str){
  return str
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="output">Script Started ...</div>
   
    <script>
      google.script.run.main();

      var i = 0;
      var refreshId = setInterval( function () { 
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = data;
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).pushMSG();
        i = i + 1;
        if (i > 10) {
          clearInterval(refreshId);
          document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "done1";
        }
      }, 500);

      function onSuccess(pushMSG) {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = data;
      }

      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "done2";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but I cannot find anyway to display the valid `data` variable ...

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your script and `I'm not looking to replace the function calls by HTML calls.`. In your script, HTML data is returned. In your goal, you want to achieve your goal without using `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(output)`. Is my understanding correct? By the way, in your script, I think that it is required to remove `.` of `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(output).`.

Comment: `'m not looking to replace the function calls by HTML calls` That is the best way.

Comment: ...and probably the only way.

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking something, but I don't fully understand why it has to be so difficult. :) Ideally it's using a hmtl page to output script status messages.

Comment: Call `main` from `html` page. `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((e)=>alert('completed'+e)).main(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer,

1. Create cache service in .gs
2. update cache key throughout several .gs functions
3. poll for cache key updates from hmtl using setInterval()

I got triggered by this very well maintained & interesting blog post:
https://ramblings.mcpher.com/gassnippets2/implementing-a-client-side-progress-bar-reporting-on-server-side-work-for-htmlservice/

Best Regards,
Kristof